# Dynamic memory allocation in a multiple-files project in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am asked to implement an analogue to the `string.h` library. However, I am not allowed to use the `'\0'` inside my library to end my string; that's why I am supposed to use a structure for strings in my program.
I have this in `mystring.h` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSTRLEN 100 // Defining the maximum lenght of the string as being 100

typedef struct scell *mystring_t;
mystring_t makemystring (char cs[]); // This function stores a given string into the mystring structure
```

I have this in `mystring.c`file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mystring.h" // including the header file of mystring library

struct scell {
    char *string;
    int length;
};

mystring_t makemystring (char cs[]){ //Storing a string into the structure

    int i = 0;
    mystring_t ns;

    ns->string=(char*)calloc(MAXSTRLEN ,sizeof(char));

    // printf ("I allocated memory for the string");

    while (cs[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf ("\nI entered into the while\n");
        ns->string[i] = cs[i];
        printf ("I inserted\n");
        i++;
        printf ("I incremented the count\n");
    }
    ns->length=i; // storing the length of the string into the structure
    printf ("%d\n", ns->length);
    printf ("refreshed the length\n");
    printf ("%d", ns->length);
    return ns;
}
```

I have this in the  `main.c` file:

```
#include "mystring.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {

int result;
mystring_t S1;
mystring_t S2;
    // create two strings
S2 = makemystring("Bye");
printf("I got out of the makemystring function\n");
S1 = makemystring("Hi");
```

These `printf()` calls are just debugging statements.
It seems to me that the function makemystring works correctly but I have a crash at the level of returning.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: One big problem: ns is a wild pointer - you never allocate any memory for the struct.

Comment: Probably you could correct your program by removing the star in the `typedef` of `mystring_t`. Another problem: If the string you pass to makemystring is longer than MAXSTRLEN you will get a buffer overflow. You should be more careful there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ns` is an uninitialized pointer when it is dereferenced:

```
mystring_t ns;

ns->string = (char*)calloc(MAXSTRLEN ,sizeof(char));
```

as `mystring_t` is a `typedef` for `struct cell*`. Allocate memory for `ns` before using:

```
mystring_t ns = malloc(sizeof(*ns)); /* No cast on return value required. */
if (ns)
{
    ns->string = calloc(MAXSTRLEN, 1);
    ns->length = 0;
}
```

*FWIW, this is one of the reasons I dislike hiding pointers in `typedef`s as it is not obvious at point of use.*

Protect going beyond the bounds of `ns->string` in the condition of the `while` loop.